# How to turn PM/AM time stamp am/pm

Tags: r, timestamp

I have a dataset with a column where date and time is stored.
The data I have is:
03/17/2020 09:30:00 PM

I want to convert AM/PM to a 24hour format.
My attempt was using this:

```
as.POSIXct(df$Date, format="%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz="UTC")
```

When I run this with the whole dataset, the majority of dates turns into "NA".
Why is this happening? I am really confused.

Comment: could you give an example where it is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using lubridate:

```
x <- "03/17/2020 09:30:00 PM"

lubridate::mdy_hms(x)
[1] "2020-03-17 21:30:00 UTC"
```

Using `as.Posixct`: note that you need the month / day convention, not the day/month:

```
as.POSIXct(x, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", tz = "UTC")
[1] "2020-03-17 21:30:00 UTC"
```